# Opengl shader vec3 not being updated

Tags: c++, opengl, colors, shader

I am trying to update the color of the triangle every frame.I am having no luck and I cannot figure out why can someone please help me.I have tried multiple times,changing the way I try to update the data every time.Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <glew.h>
#include <glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

GLuint compileshaders() {
    GLuint vshader, fshader, program;

    static const GLchar * vshadersource[] = {
        "#version 450 core                \n"
        " layout (location=0) in vec3 position;\n"
        " layout (location=1) in vec3 color;\n"
        " out vec3 color_out               ;\n"
        "void main()                  \n"
        "{                                \n"
        "color_out = color;               \n"
        "gl_Position = vec4(position,1.0);\n"
        "}                                \n"
    };

    static const GLchar * fshadersource[] = {
        "#version 450 core                \n"
        "in vec3 color_out;               \n"
        "out vec4 colorO;                  \n"
        "void main()                       \n"
        "{                                \n"
        " colorO = vec4(color_out,1.0);   \n"
        "}                                \n"
    };

    vshader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vshader, 1, vshadersource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vshader);

    fshader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fshader, 1, fshadersource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fshader);

    GLint vCompiled = 0;
    glGetShaderiv(vshader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &vCompiled);
    GLint fCompiled = 0;
    glGetShaderiv(fshader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &fCompiled);

    if (vCompiled && fCompiled != GL_FALSE) {
        program = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(program, vshader);
        glAttachShader(program, fshader);
        glLinkProgram(program);
        glDeleteShader(vshader);
        glDeleteShader(fshader);
        return program;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Shader Error!" << endl;
    }

    glDeleteShader(vshader);
    glDeleteShader(fshader);

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(0));
    GLFWwindow* window;
    GLuint program;
    GLuint vertex_array_object;
    GLuint buffers[2];

    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewInit();

    static const GLfloat positions[] =  {0.25,-0.25,0.5,0.25,0.25,0.5,-0.25,-0.25,0.5};
    static GLfloat color[] = {1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0};

    program = compileshaders();
    glUseProgram(program);
    glCreateVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_object);
    glCreateBuffers(2, &buffers[0]);
    glNamedBufferStorage(buffers[0], sizeof(positions), positions, 0);
    glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vertex_array_object, 0, buffers[0], 0,  sizeof(GLfloat) * 3);
    glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vertex_array_object, 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);
    glVertexArrayAttribBinding(vertex_array_object, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(vertex_array_object, 0);
    glNamedBufferStorage(buffers[1], sizeof(color), color, 0);
    glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vertex_array_object, 1, buffers[1], 0,   sizeof(GLfloat) * 3);
    glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vertex_array_object, 1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);
    glVertexArrayAttribBinding(vertex_array_object, 1, 1);
    glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(vertex_array_object, 1);
    glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_object);

    GLfloat clearcolor[4] = { 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0 };
    glPointSize(40);

    int width, height;
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwGetWindowSize(window, &width, &height);
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, clearcolor);

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            color[i] = (rand() % 2);
        }
        glVertexAttrib3fv(1, color);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glDeleteVertexArrays(1,&vertex_array_object);
    glDeleteProgram(program);

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> glNamedBufferStorage(buffers[1], sizeof(color), color, 0);
> ```

This tells OpenGL to copy the data *that is currently stored* in the given array into the given [buffer object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object). It does not create some linkage between `color` and the stored buffer data. OpenGL cannot know that you're modifying `color` after this command has been processed.

And `glVertexAttrib3fv` is not doing what you think it is.

If you want to change the data in an OpenGL buffer object, you have to make an OpenGL call to upload different data into the buffer.

Furthermore, you created a static buffer (the usage parameter is 0). The whole point of a static buffer is that it's *static*: its contents are fixed at the moment of its creation. So any of the uploading commands, like `glNamedBufferSubData` wouldn't work.

So you need to decide how you want to go about updating the buffer's data. Do you want to map it and change the data through the pointer? Do you want to persistenly map it? Do you want to use `glNamedBufferSubData` to update it? Do you want to invalidate the buffer before updating it? There are many strategies for updating OpenGL buffer objects.

The simplest one would be to invalidate and use `glNamedBufferSubData`, but you'll need an appropriate usage parameter for that:

```
glNamedBufferStorage(buffers[1], sizeof(color), color, GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT);
```

...

```
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    glfwGetWindowSize(window, &width, &height);
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, clearcolor);

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        color[i] = (rand() % 2);
    }

    glInvalidateBufferData(buffer[1]);
    glNamedBufferSubData(buffer[1], 0, sizeof(color), color);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. It fixed my problem